# Implementing a Custom Field on a Doctrine Entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an `Attachment` Entity in Doctrine which references a file on Amazon S3. I need to be able to provide a sort of 'Calculated Field' on the Entity that works out what I call the `downloadpath`. The `downloadpath` would be a calculated URL, for example http://site.s3.amazon.com/%s/attach/%s where I need to replace the two string values with values on the entity itself (account and filename), so;

http://site.s3.amazon.com/1/attach/test1234.txt

Although we use a Service Layer, I'd like the `downloadpath` to be available on the Entity at all times without it having to pass through the SL.

I've considered the obvious route of adding say a constant to the Entity;

`const DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'http://site.s3.amazon.com/%s/attach/%s';` and a custom `getDownloadPath()` but I'd like to keep specifics like this URL in my app's configuration, not the Entities class (also, see update below)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

**UPDATE** To add to this, I am aware now that I would need to generate a temporary URL with the AmazonS3 library to allow temporary authed access to the file - I'd prefer not to make a static call to our Amazon/Attachment Service to do this as It just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the cleanest way to do this is using the postLoad event like so;

```
<?php

namespace My\Listener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use My\Entity\Attachment as AttachmentEntity;
use My\Service\Attachment as AttachmentService;

class AttachmentPath implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Attachment Service
     * @param \My\Service\Attachment $service
     */
    protected $service;

    public function __construct(AttachmentService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(Events::postLoad);
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof AttachmentEntity) {
            $entity->setDownloadPath($this->service->getDownloadPath($entity));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, haven't found anything better.